# problem communicating with gmail imap server using fsockopen in php

Tags: php, stream, gmail, imap, fsockopen

i m able to communicate using the imap functions in php and also using the openssl from commandline ,i just wanted to try this doing fsockopen() in php.
my code is :

```
<?php

$sock=fsockopen('ssl://imap.gmail.com', '993',$errno, $errstr);
if(!$sock){
   echo $errstr;
}
else{
   fputs($sock,"a LOGIN user@gmail.com password\r\n");
   $out=fgets($sock,2000);
   fclose($sock);
   echo $out;
}

?>
```

the problem is i get just the first response from the server in $out

```
      * OK Gimap ready for requests from **.***.63.101 jj5if832612pbc.164
```

and when i change the code with the while loop for fgets ,it keeps on loading and in the end time's out without showing anything.

```
  <?php

  $sock=fsockopen('ssl://imap.gmail.com', '993', $errno, $errstr);
  if(!$sock){
      echo $errstr;
  }
  else{
      fputs($sock,"a LOGIN user@gmail.com password\r\n");
      while(!feof($sock)){
      $out.=fgets($sock,2000);
      }
 fclose($sock);
 echo $out;
 }

 ?>
```

i want to see the reply of the server in $out after i fputs the login credentials.
i m able to view my emails from command line using openssl ,so i think the problem isnt my handling of imap .
maybe i m missing something basic about file streams .

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your loop is hanging is because feof never returns true since the socket is alive until the server closes the connection. If you wait long enough, eventually the loop will break with server answering "* BYE connection closed".

```
fputs($sock,"a LOGIN user@gmail.com password\r\n");
```

Provided you used "a" before the login command, the approach I used can be very unpleasant, so change "a" to something like "1a23ef" or anything else, so that when fetching data you won't break the loop too early, also remember to use this same key before every new command with the following:

```
fputs($sock,"a1fd20 LOGIN user@gmail.com password\r\n");
while(true){
 $r = fgets($sock);
  $out .= $r;
  if(strpos($r, 'a1fd20 ') === 0){
   break;
  }
}
echo $out;
```

This worked pretty well with FETCH 1:1 RFC822 command, but if the message being fetched has the string "a1fd20 " in position 0, the loop will still break too early as well (which I don't think will happen anyways!).

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better to use standard PHP library for interaction with IMAP.
Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: As I have written in the question, I want to use fsockopen ,not for specifically imap but any server communication with php,neway thnx for responding

Comment: But you can try to check your connection problem with imap using this library.

Comment: i have already used imap library for php ,n its working der ,i also used openssl from command line ,its working der too,but only not able to figure it using fsockopen ....

Comment: I know this is old but I am having exactly the same problem, one line and when I grab the output inside the loop I get nothing, does anyone have a solution?